# Convergence of the fixed point iteration for sin(x)

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods

Sin(x) converges at x=0 as can be seen with a graphical illustration. When attempting the fixed-point iteration for sin(x) on a computer, the number gets closer and closer to zero but it does not display zero. How can we explain this?

For n = 1000000 (10^6) iterations

sin(x) using Float: 0.0017321599

sin(x) using Double: 0.0017320423900648602

For n = 10000000 (10^7) iterations

sin(x) using Float: 5.589425E-4

sin(x) using Double: 5.477222534834344E-4

Comment: ...because the only way that $\sin(x_n)=0$ is if $x_n=k\pi$...

Comment: While we can see that the convergence occurs for instance using a cobweb plot, because the derivative of $\sin$ is $1$ at the fixed point, the convergence is expected to be quite slow. Michael's answer quantifies this.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac1{\sin^2x}=\frac1{x^2}+\frac13+\frac{x^2}{15}+...$$
So every time you do a sine, $1/x^2$ increases by a third.
After $N$ iterations, $1/x^2\approx N/3$, so $x\approx\sqrt{3/N}$

Comment: You should be careful: your approximation makes sense only for small $x_0$, in which case $\frac{1}{x_0^2}$ is considerable. So $\frac{1}{x_N^2} \approx \frac{1}{x_0^2} + \frac{N}{3}=\frac{3+Nx_0^2}{3x_0^2}$. Thus $x_N \approx \sqrt{\frac{3x_0^2}{3+Nx_0^2}}$. One can drop the $3$ in the denominator once $Nx_0^2 \gg 3$...but this condition means that $N$ must be quite large, since $x_0$ was small.

Comment: (Of course, both approximations are reasonable for $x_0=0.1,N=10^6$; in this case the actual value is around $0.0017$ and the error in the approximation is less than $3 \cdot 10^{-7}$.)

Comment: The $x^2/15$ term gives an extra $1/(5N)$ or so, and $1/x_N^2$ is nearer $(N/3)+(\ln N)/5$

Comment: You still have to be careful about large $x_0$. Everything works better if you can at least assume $x_0 \in [-1,1]$, which you can do in general by considering the sequence $\sin(x_0),\sin(\sin(x_0)),\dots$ (throwing out the first term).